# How to Remove Duplicates from a column which is of ArrayType(MapType(StringType(),StringType())) in pyspark

Tags: python, list, dataframe, pyspark

I have column in dataframe which is as follows :

| Column A | Coulmn B |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [{"Test" : "Manual", "percentage" : "50"},{"Test" : "Automate", "percentage" : "80"},{"Test" -> "Manual", "percentage" : "50"},{"Test" : "Manual", "percentage" : "50"}] |
| 456 | [{"Test" : "Manual", "percentage" : "50"},{"Test" -> "Automate", "percentage" : "25"},{"Test" : "Manual", "percentage" : "50"}] |

Is there any way to remove the duplicates in the column B so that the resultant column should be as follows :

| Column A | Coulmn B |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [{"Test" -> "Manual", "percentage" -> "50"},{"Test" -> "Automate", "percentage" -> "80"}] |
| 456 | [{"Test" -> "Manual", "percentage" -> "50"},{"Test" -> "Automate", "percentage" -> "25"}] |

I have tried using distinct(), udf and array_distinct. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: It is list of Map of Strings, array(map(string,string))

Answer (score 0):

As pyspark can't compare `MapType`s for uniqueness we need sequentially do:

- transform all maps within an array into map entries with [map_entries](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_entries.html)
- remove duplicates with [array_distinct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_distinct.html)
- and eventually recover maps back from the entries with [map_from_entries](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries.html):

---

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select(df['Column A'], F.transform(
    F.array_distinct(F.transform(df['Column B'], F.map_entries)),
    F.map_from_entries).alias('Column B')
          ).show(truncate=False)
```

---

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Column A|Column B                                                                  |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|123     |[{Test -> Manual, percentage -> 50}, {Test -> Automate, percentage -> 80}]|
|456     |[{Test -> Manual, percentage -> 50}, {Test -> Automate, percentage -> 25}]|
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```